# Can you create a Microsoft Installer Transform from the cmdline?

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, windows-installer

I would like to map parameters in a .MSI by first creating a .MST at the cmdline.

This does work:

```
msiexec /i da-msi.msi PARAM_ZOT=foo,PARAM_BAZ=bang
```

All I can find is [how to create a transform](https://www.itninja.com/blog/view/downloading-installing-and-using-ms-orca) using the graphical tool [Orca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe).  It looks like there is a tool called [mstran.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msitran-exe) that *can* create an MST, but the documentation is sparse (couldn't find an example).

I want to create an MST such that I can set PARAM_ZOT=foo in the MST directly without changing one MSI, doing a msitran/torch diff.  Can I create the .MST directly to set a property without diffing against a modified version?

It seems like there should be a `set-property foo.msi VAR=VALUE` tool somewhere...

How do you do this?

Comment: How was the MSI created to begin with?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, using [WiX](https://wixtoolset.org/).  But that doesn't really matter because msiexec does work with parameters.

Comment: So Wix's `torch` command isn't what you are looking for?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, actually that would do what the question asks, but my question wasn't really clear.  I'll update the OP.